# Why this code with fork() generates Runtime Error in ejudge?

Tags: c, scanf, fork

Why this code may generate `Runtime Error` in ejudge? This program counts the number of words from `stdin` input. Words can be separated by any amount of `' '` and `'\n'`.
It seems like `fork()` can cause a problem but I am not sure why I don't get the same error on my computer.

ejudge uses gcc - Plain C, 64 bit, using -std=c11 or -std=gnu11

The task:

> On the standard input stream a text string is given which consists of
> words (a sequence of non-space characters), between which there can be
> any number of whitespace characters, including line feeds.
>
> You need to calculate the number of words if you know there are not
> more than 255, and output this value to the standard output stream.
>
> Use creating new processes so that each process reads not more than
> one word, e.g. using scanf("%s", ...).
>
> You can only output the result from the process which was started
> first (i.e. from the original program).
>
> The resulting program must return with return code 0.
>
> The size of each word does not exceed 4096 bytes.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DBG(args...) fprintf(stderr, args)
//#define DBG(args...)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t first_child;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) { // child continue reading
            char str[4097];
            if (scanf("%s", str) != EOF)
                continue;
            exit(1);
        } else {
            if (i == 1) {
                first_child = pid;
            }
            if (wait(&status) == first_child) {
                break;
            } else {
                exit(WEXITSTATUS(status) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually closing `stdout`? This may cause an error on some systems when your program exits and tries to close it again. Also, can you provide more details about the error you are getting?

Comment: Also, note that `stdin` may not produce `EOF` even after running out of actual input, this is again dependent on the environment.

Comment: Exit status is limited to 255. This won't work if the file is more than 255 lines long.

Comment: @LevM. What else could he use to tell when he's run out of input?

Comment: @LevM. Closing stdout shouldn't be a problem. All open streams are automatically closed. If `stdout` is already closed, it's not an open stream, so won't be closed again.

Comment: I think you are running afoul of some imposed limitation, such as a limit on the number of children.

Comment: @Barmar it's intended by the task that number of lines is limited to 255

Comment: Please post the task description.

Comment: @ikegami task intends that my program should create 1 + N processes, where N = number of words

Comment: @Barmar added it to question

Comment: This solution won't work because stdio uses input buffering. `scanf()` can buffer more input than the word that it returns, ad the next child process won't start reading from where it left off.

Comment: I think you need to make each child a child of the one that read the previous word, so that it will inherit the input buffer.

Comment: @Barmar, That should matter if done right because Process A is suppose to read a bit, then process B, then process C, etc. The very sequential manner means each process will use the buffer it obtained from forking.

Comment: I think `if (i == 1)` should be `if (i == 0)`.

Comment: You don't need to have n+1 simultaneous processes, though. You don't need more than two existing processes at a time. BUT, if you use the max-two-at-a-time approach, scanf becomes a problem.

Comment: Your code is very hard to follow because of your attempt to include the top process in the loop. It's more straightfoward to handle that [separately](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/38da37ee4d7312f0cdd1cceaed5df7d2)

Comment: @Barmar I realized it creates more processes than it should be. For example, if 6 were intended it creates 12. So it is the wrong algotrithm

Comment: You should only fork a new child in a previous child, not the original process.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've rewritten the solution and it passed the tests. (I posted the solution as the answer to this question)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the algorithm and it worked!
In the first version, many unnecessary forks were made. For example, if 6 were intended it created 12.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// #define DBG(args...) fprintf(stderr, args)
#define DBG(args...)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int status;
    pid_t first_pid;
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid != 0) {
        wait(&status);
        printf("%i\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        char str[4097];
        if (scanf("%s", str) == EOF) {
            DBG("PID %i\n", pid);
            exit(0);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid != 0)
            break;
    }

    DBG("PID %i waiting\n", pid);
    wait(&status);
    exit(WEXITSTATUS(status) + 1);
}
```